# Web scraping SEC site but I am receiving HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I'm web-scraping data from 13F fillings from the SEC site; however, I am running into HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. I read that using User-agents may be a solution but I am struggling to implement them into my code. Does anyone know of a way to bypass this error?

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/current?q1=0&q3=13f"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text

days_url = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'index' in link.get('href'):
        url_to_save = link.get('href')
        days_url.append(url_to_save)

days_url = days_url[0:1]
for item in days_url:
    index = 'https://www.sec.gov' + item  # contains url
    index = pd.read_html(index)
    index = index[0]
    index = index[(index['Document'].str.contains('.html')) & (
        index['Type'].str.contains('INFORMATION TABLE'))]
    try:
        index = index['Document'].iloc[0]
    except:
        pass
    print(index)
```

Which results in the following error:

http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: 403 means your request has been acknowledged by the server, and was denied. It's possible they're not happy about your "web scraping" and your IP has been blocked. Maybe try their API? https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, thanks for the quick response. I'm aware that my IP has been blocked (probably due to so many attempts to access the site). Is there any way to still use the code I have written by passing the user_agent header through?

Comment: why not use the API though? they're really trying to make it easier to access the data programmatically, while blocking automated access to the user-facing site.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I can't use their API because it doesn't have the information I am looking for (13F Forms). "Currently included in the APIs are the submissions history by filer and the XBRL data from financial statements (forms 10-Q, 10-K,8-K, 20-F, 40-F, 6-K, and their variants)."